# What's the absolute largest paper size permissible with pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, paper-size, geometry

I've had occasion to typeset [extraordinarily large matrices](http://tqft.net/EH/matrices), which I didn't seriously expect anyone to expect in detail (without a computer) or print, but I needed it to be obvious that they were completely explicit and written down *somewhere*.

By trial and error, I found a really large paper size that would compile (about 5.5m) in pdflatex and fit my matrices on a reasonable number of sheets. (I used the geometry package to choose custom page sizes.) But it would have been easier if I'd been able to find out:

> What are the limitations on paper sizes in pdflatex?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the immensely useful [TeX by Topic](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/texbytopic):

> \maxdimen 16383.99999pt; the largest legal dimension.

and

> Internally TEX works with multiples of a smallest dimension: the scaled point. Dimensions larger 
>   (in absolute value) than 2^30 − 1sp, which is about 5.75 metres or 18.9 feet, are illegal.

[Knuth delivered a beautiful extended dig at "modern" software development practices at the 2010 TUG meeting](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/an-earthshaking-announcement/), during the early part of which he referred to the value of `\maxdimen`.  I can't work out if he was serious when he suggested it had been a mistake to fix the largest dimension in TeX at this rather small value.

---

Perhaps it is worth mentioning that as far as I know, pdflatex does not apply any more restrictive limits than TeX itself for this application.  So the limitation that is relevant here is the internal TeX one.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind if I ever want to typeset a billboard using TeX.

Comment: Of course, typesetting a billboard could be done by upscaling a smaller document.  It's not like one needs 72.27sp per inch resolution...

Comment: Personally, I'm always peeved that TeX can't deal with dimensions on the order of [1 farshimmelt potrzebie](http://www.google.com/search?q=1+farshimmelt+potrzebie).

Answer (score 10):

Since you mention pdfTeX, I assume that you want to produce PDFs. The [PDF norm](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) mentions this "architectural limit":

> The minimum page size should be 3 by 3 units in default user space; the maximum should be 14,400 by
>   14,400 units. In versions of PDF earlier than 1.6, the size of the default user space unit was fixed at 1⁄72
>   inch, yielding a minimum of approximately 0.04 by 0.04 inch and a maximum of 200 by 200 inches.
>   Beginning with PDF 1.6, the size of the unit may be set on a page-by-page basis; the default remains at 1/
>   72 inch.

200 inches are 508 cm. While this limit is probably not enforced by any PDF-producing program in the TeX world, I'd advise against exceeding it.

Comment: These 14,400 units are in *user space*. But the default user space unit of 1/72 inch (the minimum) can be changed to a maximum of 75,000 (that is since PDF-1.6, I believe). That gives you a maximum of 381 kilometers in (virtual) page dimensions!