# Automatically increase PDF page height

Tags: pdf, paper-size

I'd like to emulate HTML's infinite page height using LaTeX/XeTeX, i.e. have the PDF pages grow higher until a manual `\newpage` is issued.

This could be emulated by setting a very large page height and using `pdfcrop` on the output (or just setting the page height manually), but I'd like a pure TeX variant and if possible support for footnotes etc at the bottom of the cropped page.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could use the `preview` package for this. It's basically the "pure (La)TeX variant of `pdfcrop`" you are looking for. You need to set the text height to `\maxdimen` e.g. using `geometry` and wrap every page in `\begin{preview}` ... `\end{preview}`. To do this simply have a `\begin{preview}` after `\begin{document}`, a `\end{preview}` before `\end{document}` and define a `\newpage` variant as `\end{preview}\begin{preview}`. You will loose some of the border which can be readded using the `\PreviewBorder` macro. However, AFAIK this doesn't support header and footer.

---

Here now some example code. Apparently `preview` already takes care to suppress automatic page breaks and the modification of the text height is not required.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

\renewcommand{\PreviewBorder}{1in}

\newcommand{\Newpage}{\end{preview}\begin{preview}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\lipsum
\Newpage
\lipsum[1]
\Newpage
\lipsum[1-30]
\Newpage
\lipsum[4-22]
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Enclosing the content in a `minipage` takes care of the footnotes (or would that be more restrictive than necessary?)

Comment: @pascal: If you need footnotes you can add `minipage`s. However they number footnotes differently. Floats won't work either.

Comment: This works very well --- except for floats, as you mention. I tried working around it with `\begin{figure}[h]...` but that still doesn't work because of "Not in outer par mode". Any idea of getting around that, and getting an image with a caption?

Comment: @Supernormal: The point of a float is that if floats over multiple pages to a place where it fits according to professional typesetting rules. Most users have issues understanding this at first. If you simply want to add a caption then use alternatives. The topic is further described in these posts:
[How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)
, [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)

Comment: @Supernormal: Also check out my `standalone` package which I created since I wrote this post. It is either based on `preview` or uses its own technique, depending on the used options. It can also be used to turn floats into non-floats automatically (but I'm not sure if I published that feature already).

Answer (score 11):

Another ConTeXt solution. This takes care of footnotes, but you need to mark the start and stop of the page.

```
\definestartstop[infinite]
                [before={\startTEXpage
                         \setupfootnotedefinition[location=joinedup]%
                        \startlocalfootnotes},
                 after={\placelocalfootnotes
                         \stoplocalfootnotes
                         \stopTEXpage}]

\setupTEXpage[width=\textwidth, offset=2mm]
```

which can then be used as

```
\starttext
\startinfinite
\section {Some section}
\input knuth \footnote{A random footnote}
\input ward
\stopinfinite
\stoptext
```

Comment: Wow. I really have to look into ConTeXt...

Comment: IMO nicer then the solution I've posted (from 10 years ago)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the replies, I'm using Martin's solution, from my class file:

```
\iftrue
  \usepackage[active,tightpage,psfixbb]{preview}
  \renewcommand{\PreviewBorder}{1cm}

  \newenvironment{stretchpage}%
    {\begin{preview}\begin{minipage}{\hsize}}%
    {\end{minipage}\end{preview}}
  \AtBeginDocument{\begin{stretchpage}}
  \AtEndDocument{\end{stretchpage}}

  \newcommand{\@@newpage}{\end{stretchpage}\begin{stretchpage}}

  \let\@real@section\section
  \renewcommand{\section}{\@@newpage\@real@section}
\fi
```

This works for me, if I would want to print the document, I can just disable the block.

Answer (score 1):

Martin's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19241/73340) works well up to a limited size, but TeX has an [upper limit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430/73340) on every length, including the page height. This limit is fairly small, equivalent to only around 20 sheets of letter paper placed end to end. To work around this limitation, I scaled everything in the document down by 40 times, then used `pdfposter` to scale it back up after compiling the document.

```
\newcommand{\pagescale}{0.025}  % 1/40

% Use these instead of the usual units.
\newlength{\PT}\setlength{\PT}{\pagescale pt}
\newlength{\IN}\setlength{\IN}{\pagescale in}
\newlength{\CM}\setlength{\CM}{\pagescale cm}
\newlength{\MM}\setlength{\MM}{\pagescale mm}

% LaTeX defaults are almost all defined using \p@, which is supposed to be 1pt.
\makeatletter
\setlength{\p@}{1\PT}
\makeatother

% Reset separations that were coded with pt not \p@.
\setlength{\jot}{3\PT} % Math display line separation.
\scriptspace=0.5\PT
\hfuzz=0.1\PT
\vfuzz=0.1\PT
\overfullrule=5\PT
\maxdepth=4\PT
\delimitershortfall=5\PT
\nulldelimiterspace=1.2\PT
\scriptspace=0.5\PT
\parindent=20\PT
\parskip=0\PT plus 1\PT
\abovedisplayskip=12\PT plus 3\PT minus 9\PT
\abovedisplayshortskip=0\PT plus 3\PT
\belowdisplayskip=12\PT plus 3\PT minus 9\PT
\belowdisplayshortskip=7\PT plus 3\PT minus 4\PT
\topskip=10\PT
\splittopskip=10\PT
\parfillskip=0\PT plus 1fil
\normalbaselineskip=12\PT
\normallineskip=1\PT
\normallineskiplimit=0\PT
\smallskipamount=3\PT plus 1\PT minus 1\PT
\medskipamount  =6\PT plus 2\PT minus 2\PT
\bigskipamount =12\PT plus 4\PT minus 4\PT
\def\fontsubfuzz{.4\PT}
\unitlength = 1\PT
\fboxsep = 3\PT
\fboxrule = .4\PT
\let\Oldhrule\hrule
\def\hrule{\Oldhrule height 0.4\PT}
\let\Oldvrule\vrule
\def\vrule{\Oldvrule width 0.4\PT}

\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\pagescale}

\newcommand{\marginsize}{2\CM}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5\IN,paperheight=16383pt,margin=\marginsize]{geometry}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\renewcommand{\PreviewBorder}{\marginsize}

% No point in page numbers if there is only one page.
\pagenumbering{gobble}

% Need to rerun math font definitions to get the sizes right. Loading amsfonts
% is sufficient.
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{preview}
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
\LaTeX

$\int_0^1 x^2 dx = \frac13$. \footnote{A footnote}

\hrule height \PT width 100\PT

\begin{align*}
    \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx &= \sqrt{\pi} \\
    z &= w
\end{align*}

\vrule height 100\PT

\lipsum

{\huge \lipsum

}

{\tiny \lipsum

}

% Very long example text, which couldn't fit on a single page at normal scale.
\newcount\foo
\foo=1000
\loop
    \lipsum[1]\par
    \advance \foo -1
\ifnum \foo>0
\repeat

\end{minipage}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

If you have floats then you likely want to follow [Andy's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36086/73340) advise and set `\setcounter{totalnumber}{100}`, so that LaTeX can put more of them on a page.

The following script uses [pdfposter](https://gitlab.com/pdftools/pdfposter) to scale the pdf back to its usual dimensions after it has been built.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 <scale factor> <input> <output>"
    exit 1
fi

scale=$1
newpagesize=$(pdfinfo "$2" | awk '/Page size:/ { print ('"$scale"' * $3) "x" ('"$scale"' * $5) "pt" }')

pdfposter "$2" -s "$scale" -m "$newpagesize" $3
```