# LaTeX without pages

Tags: pdf, paper-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically increase PDF page height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19237/automatically-increase-pdf-page-height)

Is it possible to have LaTeX use a single infinite page?

I don't know if the PDF file format even supports this, but I see "Screen formatted" PDFs all the time, which use a layout more pleasing to read on a monitor, but for some reason they still have pages. I don't see much point in a screen-based PDF having pages, at least when Letter and A4 options are also offered. Is there a way to make pageless documents with LaTeX?

Comment: Have a look at [Automatically increase PDF page height](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19237/automatically-increase-pdf-page-height/19241#19241), which does exactly that, but also allows for manual page breaks using `\Newpage`.

Comment: I agree that this is a duplicate, could the next person along vote to close it? Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We did experiment with a single, long page as well. We use the `geometry` package and defined

```
\geometry{paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=16383pt, left=40pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=16263pt, footskip=40pt}
```

Adjust the widths and the other parameters to your liking. Please note that a page height of more than 16383pt leads to an error. (There is an internal number somewhere that must be smaller than 2^14-1.)

Then, we got confused when `floats` where still breaking onto a new page. You also need

```
    \setcounter{totalnumber}{100}
```

to increase the number of floats allowed on one page. With a lot of floats, you might have to use the [`morefloats`](http://ctan.org/pkg/morefloats) package as well.

Comment: How well did your experiment work? I'm worried that PDF readers load a page at a time, so a giant page would lead to problems.

Comment: We did get some good results while using it as some kind of draft mode. Before, we ran into problems with `\marginpar`s running out of the bottom page. This was adjusted only in the last version to avoid work at in-between stages of the book-project. But then, it was rendered obsolete with the `marginfix` package, the package automatically adjusts the `marginpar`s.

Comment: Did you have any memory use problems or such?