# All the document in only one long and continuous page

Tags: page-breaking, geometry

Well, may be this is not really useful, but I've thought if it was possible to put all the document in one long page.

I mean, if your document is going to be read in a computer, mix all the pages in a *continuous page*.

If your document has 90 pages (A4), where each one is 21cm by 29.7cm the *continuous document* should be (more or less) one page which is 21cm by 90 · 29.7 = 2673cm.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:** Some things I would like to achieve:

- The `\newpage`, `\chapter{}`, `\part{}`, etc. shouldn't go to a *new page*, they should only add more vertical space.
- The package `pdfpages` should add the pages continuously with almost no space between them.
- The titlepage, in this case, has a different color, so it could go alone in a basic A4 page (just to make things easier).

### Question

Is this possible?

Comment: Just please, whatever you do, don't use `multicol` when you do this.

Comment: Yeah, I won't :)

Comment: Is this the same as asked yesterday ([Output a document containing a single vertical-infinite page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87787/16595))? Then there’s a solution: [Automate Fixed Width Page, length > some minimum length, but only as long as needed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27041/16595)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Well, I didn't see it, but (I think) this goes further, and needs some requirements, because that solution doesn't work with chapters, newpages, etc.

Comment: I guess it's difficult since you need to set the page dimensions of the PDF before you actually know how many lines there will be. Furthermore IIRC there are some limitations in TeX concerning the maximum page dimension.

Comment: This solves it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19237/automatically-increase-pdf-page-height

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically increase PDF page height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19237/automatically-increase-pdf-page-height)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36085/8666

Answer (score 25, accepted):

2673cm is 26.73m. The TeXBook says

> *danger* TeX will not deal with dimensions whose absolute value is
>   2^{30} sp or more. In other words, the *maximum legal
>   dimension* is slightly less than `16384pt`. This is a distance of
>   about 18.892 feet (5.7583 meters), so it won't cramp your style.

Comment: So the answer is no? If it is no, you can close this question.

Comment: I don't think the question need be closed, it is a valid question and if it is left open it is easier for other people to find it. You just have to accept the answer is no:-)

Answer (score 3):

This previous answer is not exactly true. You can create a `\vbox` with arbirtary size, so you can (for example) do

```
\setbo0=\vbox{... whole document ...}
```

The problem is, what to do with it. You can do `\shipout\box0` to print it, but the PDF page dimensions are not properly set because we need to set such page dimensions by TeX dimen registers and the mentioned limit about 5.7 meters is here. But if an interpreter of your document can handle with page dimensios a it is able to change them, then you have whole document in one column with 26 meters hight. Maybe, you have a special device which is able to print it.

If you use dvi output then `\shiput\box0` (from previous example) cerates correct output because dvi format does not care about page dimensions. These dimensions are set by the dvi driver. Maybe, you have a dvi driver which is able to print your document on skyscrapers. And if not, you can create such dvi driver.

Another possibility is to create normal (small) document but to use a `\mag` TeX primitive register. It puts to the output the scaling factor of whole document as a message for PDF interpreters or dvi drivers. So, you can prepare a small document, test it on your personal printer and then you can put `\mag` with big scaling factor. You can print the same document on airships.