# Typesetting an infinite page

Tags: header-footer, page-breaking, page-numbering, document-classes, zwpagelayout

How would I go about typesetting a document which will end up being printed on a long continuous roll of paper. The paper is 21cm wide (a vertical A4 page width) and infinitely long.

Obviously I don't want my output to be infinite in length. I just want to carry on writing without any page breaks (and consequently any page numbers).

The footers would ideally appear at the end of the text.

Comment: What would go in the footers of such a document?

Comment: I'm not expecting the actual document to be infinite. It could be for example 2.7 A4 pages long. I just don't want to manually set the page length every single time.

Comment: if your document is onepage, then try standalone class

Comment: This question is similar: [Is there a way to make “page” size match document length?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49686/is-there-a-way-to-make-page-size-match-document-length)

Comment: Similar question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87918/8666

Comment: There appear to be limits to how long pages in TeX can be, and how long pages in a PDF can be: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/420/8666

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can set the paper size manually using `geometry`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm,paperheight=500cm,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-150]
\end{document}
```

But `500cm` is not infinite.

You can use `standalone` class as suggested by touhami so that height is adjusted automatically.

```
\documentclass[border=1in]{standalone}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{21cm}
    \lipsum[1-150]
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes; and I would like this to happen automatically such that my page will scale with the amount of text I have, such that no matter how much mote text I add it will always be the right length for it.

Comment: @447xpro Use `standalone`. See the edit.

Comment: Cheers. That's what I've needed.