LaTeX infinite page height
I want a single PDF page where the page continues for as much content I have on the page, i.e. the page height increase with the content.
I have so far done so by manually increasing the geometry height like this:
\geometry{left=0.8cm,right=8.8cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm, top=0.8cm,bottom=0.8cm,footskip=2\baselineskip, paperheight=1100pt}

However, I want this to be automatic so I don't need to change the paperheight={1100pt} value if I edit the document.
Furthermore, I want the resulting PDF to be printable, so it introduces new pages every "297 mm" on the printed version (or at some page break marker).
I have no idea if this is even possible or supported by the PDF format.

I don't think that's possible with LaTeX. TeX lengths have a hard limit (I think around 5 meters...). Yep, look at the last section here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Lengths_in_LaTeX

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19237/82917

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264389/typesetting-an-infinite-page (a duplicate?)

That is a fair point. I can live with pages below that length.

The suggestion by @campa worked for getting a continuous PDF page. However, when I try to print such a PDF to paper. It just fits to one page. There seem to be no way of having the PDF break into pages only when printed.

If I understand correctly the OP wants a kind of switch between documentclasses (defined and unlimited length). So far solutions seem to offer either-or, but not both ... // A solution could be to prepare two main-files, with different documentclasses AND inputting the rest (preamble, body). Edit "the rest" and compile one of the tow mains.

I'm not sure PDF can do that. In a way, it is designed not to because it guarantees that the pagination etc. remain the same so e.g. you don't get different breaks if you're using a printer in the US versus the UK etc. It doesn't have the same goals as a format like EPUB or HTML.

Note, too, that you may run into other limitations with a page height of 5m. As far as I know, TeX ships out the page all at once. So you will have to have 5m worth of material held in memory, which is also limited. (Though you can adjust memory to some extent, if you need to.) There are limits on the numbers of various things you can use. Some of this may depend on content, whether it is a problem or not.
