# No page breaks at all

Tags: page-breaking, paper-size

Would it be possible for latex to generate the text of my latex document to a pdf consisting of one single giant, very long page. This pdf would not be for printing, but just for online viewing.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27041/automate-fixed-width-page-length-some-minimum-length-but-only-as-long-as-nee

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19237/ or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87918/ or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27041/ (and possibly others)