# Is there a way to make a webpage/scroll/unending page in LaTeX

Tags: documentclass

Is there a way to write a LaTeX document without page endings. This would make my document into a scroll of sorts, an often used format in webpages (which also have no end).

For example, Microsoft Word has the "weblayout" feature, that does what I want to achieve with LaTeX formatting.

The reason I want to do this is twofold:
1) I am distracted by page-endings in writing/editing my documents. And I don't want to be.
2) I am planning to make a webpage with my document on it, and that doesn't have pages to begin with.

Ideally there would be a website builder like google sites, but which has ingrained LaTeX support. This would also be an effective solution (since it achieves the same thing), but I haven't seen any as of yet.

Does anyone know of ways to do it?

Comment: LaTeX defaults to PDF output which is a print-oriented format. If you want something web-oriented try exporting to HTML…

Comment: The specific question of producing a PDF file which is a long scroll has been asked before. But if you want a website then LaTeX is IMO not the tool to use.

Comment: This was easier to find: [No page breaks at all](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290866/5764)