# Toilet paper format

Tags: templates, document-classes

I am currently writing a document using `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}` (very classic, good and all).

But I want to change it to a *continuous page*, a bit like a TP roll. Any idea how?

Comment: We had this question recently -- by you, most likely

Comment: Not by me, but if you stumble across it, I'll close this question. It is more for my writing comfort that I ask this.

Comment: Related? [All the document in only one long and continuous page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87918/all-the-document-in-only-one-long-and-continuous-page)

Comment: Ok, thanks, there is indeed a lot of trouble if I want to do it.

Comment: Unrelated: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwxqi.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this? Faking a `long` page height with 500cm and removing top and bottom margins, but there will be a distinguished separation at the page boundary.

TeXnically the a dimension register is restricted to `16384pt`, which is about 5.73m.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[paperheight=500cm,paperwidth=10cm,vmargin={0pt,0pt},left=1cm,right=1cm,headheight=0pt]{geometry}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[1000]
\end{document}
```