# Class without paging

Tags: pdf, document-classes

Is there a class of LaTeX that does not divide the pages?

I contextualise a bit the question. Some time ago I was talking with some colleagues and we were discussing that most of the time, nowadays, we look at mathematics articles on screen, instead of paper, and the division in pages sometimes feels "weird", while the structure of a webpage (just scrolling without changing pages) would feel more natural, especially on touch devices and small papers.

So, is there a way to produce such a thing in LaTeX, so a long PDF or DVI that is just a very long page with everything inside?

EDIT: The [Toilet paper format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320025/61085) is not a duplicate of this, since the solution there renders a document with more than one page.

EDIT 2: It is indeed a duplicate of [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27041/61085).

Comment: [Toilet paper format](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320025)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Since toilet paper is a dupe, better close this one as dupe of the original dupe, not of the dupe dupe? (<- No idea if that makes sense at all)

Comment: Toilet paper is not a solution to my question, since there are still break pages there. I'll have a look at the other questions marked as duplicates of that.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27041/automate-fixed-width-page-length-some-minimum-length-but-only-as-long-as-nee) fits better, since it just produces one page (and this question suits more as a duplicate). Unfortunately, there is still [this TeX issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420/whats-the-absolute-largest-paper-size-permissible-with-pdflatex) with maximum dimensions, that seems not to be avoidable.

Comment: @Johannes_B yes but it has more links to other almost dupes that's why i chose that one