# Dynamically enlarge the height of a page

Tags: geometry, height, page

There is a way to dynamically enlarge a page in a LaTeX document? the thing I want is to have a document which will always have a single page, so the page should increase in height to hold all the document contents.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87918/21930

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is possible `:)`

You can use the `standalone` class with the `varwidth` option to make the size automatically adjustable.

It can't get infinitely big (no computer can handle infinity) but this example code makes a 2.1 m wide and 5.6 m high page (in less than 7 seconds):

```
\documentclass[varwidth=500cm,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-150]
\lipsum[1-150]
\lipsum[1-150]
\lipsum[1-150]
\lipsum[1-150]
\lipsum[1-150]
\lipsum[1-150]
\lipsum[1-150]
\lipsum[1-150]
\end{document}
```

The argument you pass to `varwidth` is the width of the page, and its height grows dynamically.

If the page goes beyond 5.7 m tall TeX will complain, but long before that your PDF viewer will hang and you won't be able to read anything:

> [image]

[image]

Your turn MS Office :)

Comment: wow, that is just what I was looking for, perfect. 

Thanks.