# How do we get unlimited pageheight?

Tags: geometry

I would like to set a page that has a height of 6 meters. The following code fails.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=600cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty:995: Dimensi
on too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.995 \Gm@process
```

My code compiles fine with `500cm` instead of `600cm`. Therefore, what I am asking for should be possible. Is there a way to increase the limit or a better to achieve the goal?

Comment: Hi. Please see this question and answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87918/

Comment: you can not have a length larger than `\maxdimen`

Comment: Thank you both and apologies. I did not find that question before. It's a pity that this is not possible.

Comment: Do you actually have access to a printer with a 2 meter page size?  Does the print driver scale?

Comment: I no longer print on paper, John. Therefore, I also do not need pages and breaks. That I cannot have it, or rather: that I must have these, I still find it difficult to believe.