# Dynamically increasing paper height, rather than breaking page

Tags: page-breaking, geometry, paper-size

Package `geometry` allows specification of paper height, e.g., `\geometry{paperheight=782mm}`,

What about dynamically adjusting paper height — How to dynamically increase paper height, rather than breaking pages?

LaTeX has page breaking logic, tweak to increase paper height by length necessary to avoid break.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87918

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you familiar with the `\enlargethispage` command?

Comment: What about `\smash` together with forcing a manual pagebreak?

Answer (score 1):

Observing 16383pt [limit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87935/300519) on page height

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=174mm,paperheight=16383pt,margin=8mm}
```

dynamically increase when attempting page break

```
\usepackage{everyshi}
\EveryShipout{%
    \pdfpageheight=\pagetotal
    \advance\pdfpageheight by 16mm %top and bottom margin
    \advance\pdfpageheight by \textheight
    \advance\pdfpageheight by -\pagegoal
}
```

(Variant of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49712/300519 for my purposes.)