# How to make unlimited sheet of paper in LaTeX?

Tags: geometry, paper-size

How can I make LaTeX to do the unlimited (just as big, as the content) sheet of paper?

So everything goes right on the one page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36085/8666

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The package `incgraph` provides an environment `inctext` which does exactly what you look for. The text or graph or whatever determines the paper size.
That means, width and height of the paper are both determined by the content. This could be useful e.g. for drawing pictures. I added an example where a `tikzpicture` is drawn on the second sheet of paper (without using the externalization library which is brillant but often a pain).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{inctext}
  Whatever
\end{inctext}

\begin{inctext}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[fill=yellow!50!white] (0,0) circle (11mm);
    \path[fill=white] (0,0) circle (9mm);
    \foreach \w/\c in {90/red,210/green,330/blue}
    {\path[shading=ball,ball color=\c] (\w:1cm) circle (7mm);}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{inctext}
\end{document}
```

The picture actually shows TWO sheets of paper with the Adobe Reader.

[image]

Comment: Using your package also the width of the page is determined by the contents of the document, am I right?

Comment: Also if I add `\usepackage{lipsum}` and `\lipsum` inside the document I get `! Dimension too large.` error.

Comment: Yes, the contents determine the actual width. If you use `\lipsum` without anything else, this gives a VERY long line (too long!). If you use e.g. a minipage of a certain width to envelope the lipsum text it should work as you may want to - as long as the contents do not extend TeX's maximal dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the info. BTW, why don't you put a more detailed answer (including the explanation in your comment) in those answers of which this one has been made "duplicate of"?

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: +1: for [incgraph](http://ctan.org/pkg/incgraph)! Looks amazing! `:)`

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I've inserted your package in the [list of packages maintainers](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1181/27635)

Comment: @karlkoeller I've extended my answer and added some application example.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm +1: really very interesting!