# Insert graphic with tikz without margin

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, margins

I have to insert a graphic into the whole page with tikz. The graphic has the same size as the final document. I use tikz because I have to insert some drawing and some text into the graphic. My problem now is, that some margin is inserted to. How to avoid this margin?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
    total={512pt,512pt},
    papersize={512pt,512pt}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=512pt,height=512pt]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that the image doesn't fit. The warning says overfull hbox and I get an empty first page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to creat a document with only one page and sized according size of an inserted graphic, [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class can help you. It crops the output file to contents.

Following code uses `TiKZ` to insert a graphics as a tikzpicture node. Every node contains certain `inner sep` between its contents and border. With `inner sep=0pt` there won't be any white margin around the inserted graphics.

Being the inserted graphic node, it can be used as reference for adding text or paintings over it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% start of gratuitous packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (graphic) {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
    \draw[red, line width=1mm] (graphic.center) circle (13mm);
    \node[draw, fill=white, below right=1cm of graphic.north] {this is some text};
    \node[draw, rounded corners, fill=green!20, above right=15mm and 2cm of graphic.south west] {$\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x = 1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative solution could be using [`incgraph`](http://ctan.org/pkg/incgraph) package. Some examples:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287054/1952
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136946/1952
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122215/1952

Comment: `node[inner sep=0pt]` was the clue. I didn't think of it. That was exactly, what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It takes two runs to locate the image correctly.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% start of gratuitous packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
    total={512pt,512pt},
    papersize={512pt,512pt}]{geometry}
    \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-13pt}
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-13pt}
    \addtolength{\topmargin}{-4pt}
\usepackage{tikz}% start of required packages
\usepackage{mwe}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted but it works for this example. I wanted to avoid the margin of Tikz because it is possible, that further  graphics aren't paperwidth and paperheight.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136900/insert-a-full-page-image?s=1|3.0985