# Is it possible to create a PDF document of undefined, variable height with Latex?

Tags: pdf, paper-size

I would like to create a PDF document with `LateX`, whose width is fixed but whose height is variable.

What do I mean by variable? I mean that the document will have a priori one page, but that the length of this page will adapt to the content. One can imagine a minimal height, but if there is a lot of text, then the height of the page gets bigger.

Maybe I need to use `TeX` to do this.

If anyone has some clues about how to achieve that, or has some commentary on this topic, I would be grateful.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19237/automatically-increase-pdf-page-height

Comment: I will test it later but it seems to be what I am looking for.