# Include pdf file with different paper size

Tags: pdf, pdfpages

I'm finishing my master thesis project with latex (A4 paper size) and I need to include a few drawings in pdf (paper size A3), so I tried to use this:

```
\includepdf[pages={-}, noautoscale]{./files/drawings/file1.pdf}
```

but the page generated is size A4. Is it possible to have different paper sizes?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179718/how-to-have-a-precise-control-on-the-size-of-each-page/179823#179823, please

Comment: I searched before posting but I didn't found that links, thank you very much!