# How to log the value of a variable?

Tags: lengths, logging

I am debugging a set of macros. The error seems to come from `\vspace*{\dimexpr0.000000cm-\topskip plus 1fill}`.

**How can I log the value of the length?**

I have tried `\typeout{\dimexpr0.000000cm-\topskip plus 1fill}` but it does not work.

Comment: `\the\dimexpr...`

Comment: you can not use `plus` after a skip register, a skip register is a complete glue specification, conversely you can use `plus` after a dimen register as that is just the natural width

Comment: `\vspace*{\glueexpr 0pt plus 1fill - \topskip\relax}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\dimexpr` accepts only rigid lengths; if you pass it a rubber length parameter, it is coerced to a rigid length by suppressing the stretch and shrink components; so you can say

```
\dimexpr 0pt - \topskip\relax
```

which is a complicated way to say `-1\topskip`. However, `plus` is illegal in `\dimexpr`. You want

```
\vspace*{\glueexpr 0pt plus 1fill - \topskip\relax}
```

Here is an interactive session, notice the error at `plus`:

```
> pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\relax
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.

*\showthe\topskip
> 10.0pt.
<*> \showthe\topskip

? 

*\showthe\dimexpr0.000000cm-\topskip plus 1fill\relax
> -10.0pt.
<to be read again> 
                   p
<*> \showthe\dimexpr0.000000cm-\topskip p
                                         lus 1fill\relax
? 11
<*> ...dimexpr0.000000cm-\topskip plus 1fill\relax

? 

*\showthe\glueexpr0pt plus 1fill - \topskip\relax
> -10.0pt plus 1.0fill.
<*> ...the\glueexpr0pt plus 1fill - \topskip\relax

? 

*\stop
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

If you want to debug such a `\vspace` non interactively, use something like

```
\typeout{***This vertical space will be \the\glueexpr0pt plus 1fill - \topskip\relax}
```

This will write the glue in the .log file.

Comment: OK, thanks. This goes far beyond my knowledge.

Comment: It seems that you corrected my code but did not answer my question... Can I "log" (in a way or in another) the value passed to `vspace`? Thanks!

Comment: @Colas You could redefine `\vspace` to write something to the log file. But so long as the syntax is correct, why bother?

Comment: I tried `\typeout{\glueexpr 0pt plus 1fill - \topskip\relax}` but it prints `[...]*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
\glueexpr 0pt plus 1fill - \topskip \relax 
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}][...]`. I bother because [this code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179823/8323) does not what it is supposed to do in some situations.

Comment: @Colas `\typeout{\the\glueexpr...\relax}`. I used `\showthe` that's the “non interactive” counterpart of `\the`.

Comment: OK, thanks. It prints `-0.00002pt plus 1.0fill`. My problem is that it fills to much space I think.

Comment: How does one launch the interactive mode?