# Customizing the height of the pages

Tags: pdftex, paper-size

## The question

*I would like to control the height of the pages of the `PDF` documents I produce with `LaTeX`.*

Starting with a `LaTeX` document and two parameters:

- a **given page size**  (`heightPage` and `widthPage`)
- a **given length** called `initialVerticalInset`,

I would like to produce a `PDF` whose page lengths follow the pattern

- the normal height of the pages is `heightPage`
- **BUT**, the height of the first page is `(heightPage - initialVerticalInset)`
- **AND**, the height of the last page equals the "height of its content", i.e. "the last page is cut" after the end of its content

*If possible*, I would like also :

- if any of these pages are put next to another one, the baselines should be aligned
- the margins could be set a minimal value (such as `0pt`)

---

## Example 1

[image]

[image]

---

## Example 2

[image]

---

## Minimal documents to be tested

In a [previous similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179718/how-to-have-a-precise-control-on-the-size-of-each-page), I noticed that one difficulty could be the compatibility with :

- `itemize` environments
- `mdframed` environments
- the case of short documents has to be dealt with too.

So, I prepared three MWE to be tested.

### Short document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm, paperheight=10cm, hmargin=0mm, 
    top=0mm, bottom=0mm] {geometry}

\setlength{\initialVerticalInset}{4.5cm}


\begin{document}

This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? 

\end{document}
```

### Documents with `itemize` environments

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm, paperheight=10cm, hmargin=0mm, 
    top=0mm, bottom=0mm] {geometry}


\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\initialVerticalInset}{4.5cm}


\begin{document}


This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it?

This is a test:
\begin{itemize}
\item Hello

\item This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test.

\item Good Bye

\item Hello

\item This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test.
\end{itemize}

This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it?

This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it?

This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? 
\end{document}
```

### Documents with `mdframed` environments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=15cm,
  paperheight=15cm,
  hmargin=1cm,
  vmargin=0cm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz, needspace=1.5cm]{mdframed}

\newmdenv[%
innerleftmargin = 2mm,
innerrightmargin = 2mm,
innertopmargin = 2mm,
innerbottommargin = 2mm,
leftmargin = 0mm,
rightmargin = 0mm,
splitbottomskip = 2mm,
splittopskip = 4mm,
middlelinewidth = 0mm,
linecolor = red,
backgroundcolor = red,
roundcorner = 0pt,
skipbelow = 0mm,
skipabove = 0mm,
]{mybox}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\initialVerticalInset}{5cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: given the cut last page requirement are you not adding page head and foot, or just not adding foot on last page or ...

Comment: No, I don't need to add page foot. Actually. In what I want to do, there is no page head or foot (I don't do anything special about them).

Comment: Do you really not think that either of the solutions to your previous question is worthy of your acceptance? It really is not fair to ask a difficult question to which you receive sophisticated solutions, with significant follow-up in some cases, and then say 'well, I won't accept your answer unless you also solve this, this, and this further problem'. This is especially true when you are asking questions which cannot possibly be answered in ways which will be robust under all possible scenarios.

Comment: @cfr I will accept answers. I have not done it yet because, even since theses answers are great (and impressive), they don't answer perfectly my question. But I see your point also. (note also that I have given bounties)

Comment: @Colas Maybe I missed something but I thought they answered your original question i.e. before you edited it with additional requirements. Apologies if I'm mistaken about that.

Comment: This is good task for plain TeX: there are no mdframed nor itemize environments and all processing of baselines are under your own control. And the medium height is changed simply by `\pdfpageheight=...`

Comment: @wipet You mean rather like [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179835/)? (Except for the misplaced addition which has been edited in?)

Comment: @cfr, actually, @wipet 's answer is great but the first page if of arbitrary length (with his command `\firstpage{...}`), which is not what I am looking for :(

Comment: Wouldn't the "geometry" package do exactly what you need ?

Comment: I guess it is too complicated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem with this answer

### Floating objects

I have tried to see if this answer works with `figure` environments. If they appear to be at the last page, then it does not work as wanted (the last page has the `\normalHeigt` and not the "clipping height")

PS:
Since I don't know anything about `TeX` and I am not a super user of `LaTeX`, maybe there are mistakes or bad syntax. **If you think the following code can be improved, please comment!**

## Answer

This answer is elaborated on touhami's answer.

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Parameters
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newlength{\initialHeight}
\setlength{\initialHeight}{5.5cm}

\newlength{\normalHeight}
\setlength{\normalHeight}{10cm}

\newlength{\normalWidth}
\setlength{\normalWidth}{10cm}

\newlength{\horizontalMargin}
\setlength{\horizontalMargin}{0mm}

\newlength{\topMargin}
\setlength{\topMargin}{0mm}

\newlength{\bottomMargin}
\setlength{\bottomMargin}{0mm}
% This is a crucial line
% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268943/8323
\setlength{\maxdepth}{0pt}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Size
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[paperwidth=\normalWidth, 
            paperheight=\initialHeight,
            left=\horizontalMargin,
            right=\horizontalMargin,
            top=\topMargin,
            bottom=\bottomMargin]{geometry}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Core
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter


% Set the vertical size of the page
%
\newcommand{\setnewvsize}[1]{%
\global\paperheight\dimexpr#1\relax%
\global\pdfpageheight\paperheight%
\global\textheight\dimexpr\paperheight - \bottomMargin - \topMargin\relax%
\global\@colht\textheight%
\global\@colroom\textheight%
\global\vsize\textheight%
}

% Change the vsize after the first page
% (after the first output)
%
\newcommand\firstPassageInOutput{1}
\let\mt@outputpage\@outputpage
\def\@outputpage{\mt@outputpage\ifnum\firstPassageInOutput=1\setnewvsize\normalHeight\renewcommand\firstPassageInOutput{0}\fi}


% Change the vsize after the last page
%
\AtEndDocument{%
% The following line is needed is the case when the last page is only one line
\vskip-\lastskip\nobreak\par\vskip0pt\par
% Core
\global\paperheight\dimexpr\pagetotal + \bottomMargin + \topMargin \relax%
\global\pdfpageheight\paperheight%
\global\textheight\dimexpr\pagetotal
}
\makeatother




\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
lipsum{}
\end{document}
```

## Outputs of the MWE to be tested

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the natural idea. Some remark 1) `\dimexpr` end optionally by `\relax` not obligatory but good practice 2) `\global` declares the following definition or assignment to be global.

Comment: @touhami I made some improvements following your remarks. I have also added also some `\global\@colht\textheight`, etc. although I don't know what is it for.

Comment: `final tuning
% (don't really know what I'm doing here)` this is not necessart. `\begin{document}` will do this for you.

Comment: I think you don't really need `\normalWidth` and `\initialHeight`.

Comment: I like variables!

Comment: good work, almost complete.

Comment: Please don't award the bounty immediately to me, you have one week, if better answers come just choose the best.

Comment: Why "almost"? Do you see any drawback to this solution?

Comment: I think yes, for now floats in last page.

Comment: You were right, `float` creates a problem... Do you have an idea on how to deal with it? PS: if you have a solution that implies a double-run compilation, it is fine!

Comment: A similar problem with footnotes. I think a good solution need redefine the output routine. Now, for figures (tables) one can  use `caption` package `{\par\centering \includegraphics{myfigure}
\refstepcounter{figure}\captionof{figure}[\figurename: \thefigure]{bla bla}\label{fig:bla}}` good luck.

Comment: @touhami Thanks, I will have a look at that. I don't use footnotes.

Comment: Sorry, there is no need to `\refstepcounter{figure}`.

Answer (score 5):

I think this does the job. Thnaks to the idea `\pdfpageheight=\pagetotal` from wipet's answer [How to have a precise control on the size of each page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179718/how-to-have-a-precise-control-on-the-size-of-each-page/179835#179835)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\initialVerticalInset}
\setlength{\initialVerticalInset}{4.5cm}

\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm, 
            paperheight=-\dimexpr\initialVerticalInset- 10cm\relax,
            margin=0mm]{geometry}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\setnewvsize}[1]{%
\global\paperheight\dimexpr#1+\initialVerticalInset\relax%
\global\pdfpageheight\paperheight%
\global\textheight\paperheight%
\global\@colht\textheight \global\@colroom\textheight \global\vsize\textheight%
\global\initialVerticalInset=0pt}


\let\mt@outputpage\@outputpage
\def\@outputpage{\mt@outputpage\setnewvsize\paperheight}

\makeatother

\AtEndDocument{\initialVerticalInset=0pt\vskip-\lastskip\nobreak\par\vskip1pt\par\setnewvsize\pagetotal}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it?

This is a test:
\begin{itemize}
\item Hello

\item This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test.

\item Good Bye

\item Hello

\item This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test.
\end{itemize}

This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it?

This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it?

This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? This is a test. This is a longer sentence with some more words, isn't it? 

\end{document}
```

**Itemize**

[image]

**mdframed**

[image]

**Example 2 pages only**

[image]

**Example only one page**

[image]

Comment: Hi touhami, so far your macro works great, but there is a little problem. As you can see for example in the last picture you have put, the last line of text is cut very sharply. It is cut on the base line, and the comma is not wholly visible. The same problem would happen with letters such as `g`, `p`, etc. So you see a way to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to modify the margins of `geometry`, but it breaks everything... Just change `margin=0mm` to  `margin=1mm` and will see (In the Example with only one page). Thanks!

Comment: I don't need to change the margins in the middle of the document. I tried to change the margins because of the first problem, but what I really need is `margin=0mm`. I pointed out the `margin≠0mm` problem just in case of. Thanks

Comment: @Colas answer edited. I use `\AtEndDocument{\initialVerticalInset=0pt\vskip-\lastskip\nobreak\par\vskip1pt\par\setnewvsize\pagetotal}` this help for the first problem

Comment: Your edit solves the problem for the very last page, but it does not solve it for the other pages. See for example the first document "Itemize" (with `\setlength{\initialVerticalInset}{5cm}`). Thanks

Comment: @Colas this is because of `margin=0mm`

Comment: Yes, you are right. So, in order to solve this issue, I would to add, let's say `x`mm as a bottom margin. Can your macro be compatible with this case? Thanks!

Comment: I have tried to work out the "bug", see my answer to the question. Feel free to improve it (for instance, I don't know what `global` means, etc.). Anyway, I will give you a bounty for your great answer! Thanks!