# Longtable appears to prevent \enlargethispage from working

Tags: longtable, tabu

The following code works for me, but if I remove the comment and thus add the longtabu/longtable, then the \enlargethispage loses its effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\small\thepage}
\begin{document}
\enlargethispage{-2cm}
%\begin{longtabu}{Xl} a&b\\ \end{longtabu}
%\begin{longtable}{ll} a&b\\ \end{longtable}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

How do I work around this?

Comment: note that longtable uses a different page breaker (output routine) `\enlargethispage` is a feature of the standard one, so it's not that longtable stops it working, more a feature request that the feature be added to longtable's.

Comment: Are you inclined to approve of this request, because I would be happy to create one. In the end I just want to solve the question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267067/newgeometry-and-afterpage-dont-adjust-the-geometry from earlier with longtable present. So an alternative without `\enlargethispage` is entirely helpful as well.

Comment: In your example you can simply put the `\enlargethispage` behind the longtable.

Comment: @Ulrike This example is misleading in that way. The end goal is a document class. So far I use `\AtBeginDocument{\enlargethispage{-2cm}}`. I cannot know if longtable is part of the game or not and if it will be on the page of the header.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267128/71471

Comment: @touhami, your solution solves the other question, but not this one. If I understand `longtable` correctly then it is due to the changed output routine ignoring the `\textheight`.

Comment: Is this about `longtable` or `longtabu`? The question says one. The code says another. (I don't know if it makes a difference to the problem, but I avoid `longtabu` on principle, so it makes a difference to me.)

Comment: The `\enlargethispage` command in `latex` sets the insert `\@kludgeins` which is in turn honoured by the `\output` routine. The `longtable` package redefines said output routine and replaces it with its own, that doesn't know about the `\@kludgeins` and thus in effect breaks the command. I have a rough idea where to patch it in, but have so far not been successfull. I found the problem with `longtabu`, but the root cause is in `longtable` which is what provides the page breaking behaviour to `longtabu`. I changed the sample to reflect this.

Comment: you can see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213750/customizing-the-height-of-the-pages/265893#265893

Comment: another way is `\usepackage[margin=2cm,bottom=4cm,showframe]{geometry}` this set text height -2cm and  `\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\afterpage{%
\global\addtolength\textheight{2cm}%
\global\setlength{\@colht}{\textheight}%
}}
\makeatother` will add 2cm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. Newcommand `\enlargemypage` to be used.

**Edit** the command work with or without `longtable`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\small\thepage}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Enlargemypage}[1]{%
\global\addtolength\textheight{#1}%
\global\setlength{\@colht}{\textheight}%
\global\setlength{\@colroom}{\textheight}%
\global\setlength{\vsize}{\textheight}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\enlargemypage}[1]{%
\Enlargemypage{#1}\afterpage{\Enlargemypage{-#1}}}

\AtBeginDocument{\enlargemypage{-2cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ll} a&b\\\end{longtable}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't think this solves it. I don't necessarily need the page with longtable on it to be larger, but the first page in the document and it can happen or not happen that this page contains a longtable.  So adding this after longtable won't help I am afraid.

Comment: @Max in this case just use `\enlargemypage{-5cm}` (updated version)  after `\begin{document}`

Comment: @Max answer edited `\AtBeginDocument{\enlargemypage{-2cm}}` is used.

Comment: It works for the sample, but unfortunately not for my document. I guess I can make it work though. I was hoping for a real solution within longtable, but since no one else has answered yet, I will award the bounty, least it goes to waste.

Comment: Ok, but I can't see the problem, for me it works fine (I don't use tabu), did you see my last comment below your question?