# How to make the margins relative to the actual content rather than the baseline?

Tags: margins, geometry

I need to have small margins in my document.
It seems that the margins are relative to the baselines rather than the content.

See this example, where the content is cut out of the page:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm, 
            paperheight=3.2cm,
            margin=0mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

We have
\[ A= 2^{N-2}  \]
\[ B= 2^{N-1}  \]
\[ C= 2^{N-2}-\frac{(1+i)^N+(1-i)^N}{4}  \]
\[ D= 2^{N-2}+\frac{(1+i)^N+(1-i)^N}{4}  \]

\end{document}
```

**How to make the margins relative to the actual content rather than the baseline? Is it possible?**

Comment: what do yo mean the content of the page or the papersize?

Comment: I mean the content: in this document, the last fraction should be visible, for instance.

Comment: @touhami "the last fraction should be visible": I mean there should be a second page with the last equation, so that it is visible.

Comment: this seem not simple. One can try  encourage pagebreak. In your example you can try `\setlength{\topskip}{8pt}`.

Comment: if last fraction go to second page there will be more than `0mm` bottom margin.

Comment: Yes but more is better than less ;-) I think it is a problem if LaTeX just cuts out a part of the content instead of starting a new page.

Comment: so try `\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm, 
            paperheight=3.2cm,
            margin=0mm,bottom=.5\baselineskip]{geometry}`

Comment: Related? [How can I create a PDF document exactly as big as my `tikz` picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452/5764)

Comment: @touhami I've played a little bit with your solution and it seems to work. You can add an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to get, but the explanation about the cropped part is easy: the last baseline sits at the bottom of the paper, because of `margin=0pt`; however, LaTeX allows the depth of the last line to be at most 5pt before taking countermeasures. The relevant parameter is `\maxdepth`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm,
            paperheight=3.2cm,
            margin=0mm]{geometry}

\setlength{\maxdepth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

We have
\[ A= 2^{N-2}  \]
\[ B= 2^{N-1}  \]
\[ C= 2^{N-2}-\frac{(1+i)^N+(1-i)^N}{4}  \]
\[ D= 2^{N-2}+\frac{(1+i)^N+(1-i)^N}{4}  \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will test it but It looks like what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As typography goes this is bad practice, but I suspect it is precisely what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm,showframe,
            paperheight=3.2cm,
            margin=0mm,bottom=5pt]{geometry}
\lineskip 1pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
\begin{document}

We have
\[ A= 2^{N-2}  \]
\[ B= 2^{N-1}  \]
\[ C= 2^{N-2}-\frac{(1+i)^N+(1-i)^N}{4}  \]
\[ D= 2^{N-2}+\frac{(1+i)^N+(1-i)^N}{4}  \]

\end{document}
```

The `5pt` bottom margin appears to be a magic number for any descenders (any font size), even using a default `\lineskip`.

---

Even more dramatic results can be obtained using:

```
\lineskip=0pt plus 1fil
\begin{document}
\baselineskip=0pt
```

---

The downside is that only descenders (anything below the baseline) will go below the bottom margin.

An alternative is to put the baseline at the very bottom of each equation using `\raisebox`, only you can't put display mode math inside a `\raisebox` (at least not without using a `\parbox`, which leads to too much vertical space).  Anyway, the following fakes display mode math (without equation numbers).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm,
            paperheight=3.2cm,
            margin=0pt]{geometry}

\newcommand{\mybox}[1]% #1 = contents
{\ifvmode\vskip\lineskip\else\newline\fi
 \centerline{\raisebox{\depth}{$\displaystyle #1$}}%
 \vskip\lineskip}

\lineskip=1pt plus 1fil

\begin{document}
We have
\mybox{ A= 2^{N-2}  }
\mybox{ B= 2^{N-1}  }
\mybox{ C= 2^{N-2}-\frac{(1+i)^N+(1-i)^N}{4}  }
\mybox{ D= 2^{N-2}+\frac{(1+i)^N+(1-i)^N}{4}  }
\end{document}
```

[image: raisebox solution]

Comment: This works for this precise document but I am looking for a generic solution.

Comment: Further experiments have shown that a 5pt bottom margin is enough to force the last line to the next page before it runs off the bottom of the page.  I've replaced the bottom line with \rule[-13pt]{10pt}{26pt) and replaced the bottom 2 lines with \rule[-25pt]{10pt}{50pt) and can still see white below the bottom.

Comment: Maybe it is equal to `.5\baselineskip`?

Comment: @Colas - Changing \baselineskip seems to have little effect, other than to change the minimum line spacing.  This is better seen by adding another line so that the page is not terminated by \end{document}.  Nor does it seem related to \lineskiplimit, whose default value is 0pt.