# Large pages with minimum page-breaking

Tags: page-breaking, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the absolute largest paper size permissible with pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420/whats-the-absolute-largest-paper-size-permissible-with-pdflatex)

I want a long document to fit in a single page. That would make proofreading easier for me.

The most I got so far were a few `1500 mm` pages. It seems that `5000 mm` pages can have at most `1500 mm` of text before pagebreaks are inserted. In other words, the same number of pages is created by either:

```
\usepackage[margin=1in, paperheight=1500mm]{geometry}
```

or

```
\usepackage[margin=1in, paperheight=5000mm]{geometry}
```

How can I make pages not to break at `1500 mm` in a `5000 mm` page?

Comment: My question is about page-breaking too. A 5 meters page, it seems, can have only 1.5 meter of text. The remaining 3.5 meters are blank. Thanks.

Comment: You can actually push the page size to `200in` (or `5080mm`). I'm *not* receiving your `1.5m` maximum of the text block when I use your setting `\usepackage[margin=1in,paperheight=200in]{geometry}`. What did you test your text with? `\lipsum` only produces 150 paragraphs of text which fills a `200in` page about 80%. You must be inserting a manual page break, or doing something different. Use the [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) and insert `\lipsum[1-150]\lipsum[1-150]` (300 paragraphs) as your document content *only*. Does the text still stop @ `1.5m`?

Comment: Yep. And the content produced by `\lipsum` gets cluttered as if two pages were typeset one over the other. (TeXLive 2012 and xdvi). Thanks!

Comment: @NicolaiRostov: ...Mmmm, xdvi. What about compiling with `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Werner: Output from `pdflatex` is fine: `200in` of text. Thanks! So should I abandon the `dvi` format?

Comment: @NicolaiRostov: Like it's toast that's been left on the counter for two weeks, yes. There's not much motivation for keeping it in that format, in my opinion.