Best approach to ensure that typeset paragraph is free of /r/n whitespace characters
Consider a use-case where one is copying a paragraph from a typeset .pdf for insertion into a field of a webform or .pdf form which supports multiples lines / paragraphs.  The typesetting process naturally inserts /r/n at all the right (wrong in this context) places.
Next consider a need to manually delete line breaks in the destination field on that webform such that your content seems to fill the dimensions of the field you're pasting into.
One might instead use a text editor supporting regular expressions replace as an intermediate step to remove the /r/n sequences, and then paste the cleaned text in the destination field.
For editing and polishing, one obviously benefits from standard formatting with line breaks.  After the paragraph has been polished, and is ready to be entered into some form, one might benefit from a single (possibly quite long) line of text that can be easily selected for copy/paste and will be free of line breaks.
An ideal solution would involve a toggle, switch or .sty file option whereby in editing mode one has standard formatting, while in content deployment mode, one essentially will see a very wide document (essentially being driven by the number of characters the longest paragraph in your document) from which content can be easily copied for pasting in fields of webforms and .pdf forms.
How might this be supported?

there are normally no /r/n in a PDF. If you get line breaks from copy&paste it is from a heuristic of your PDF viewer, and PDF viewer can differ here a lot.

in a standard (non tagged) pdf there are no white space characters at all, the visible characters are just placed in the page by coordinate and any visible white space is just the gaps between the placed characters. Any space or newline characters produced by cut and paste are an artifact of your pdf reader guessing that they should be there

This is really asking to do the reverse of what TeX is designed to do. You don't edit the typeset document. In that sense, the typeset document is the 'deployment' target. So if you don't want it in that format, I'd agree that changing the format of the target is the way to go. But I'm not sure creating an indefinitely wide PDF is a good option, even if it was possible. Maybe produce something like HTML instead? (I mean from .tex you can produce .html.) Then you won't hit the maximum dimension issue if you write a long paragraph.

A questions that comes to mind is then: Any examples of a .pdf viewer which can be configured to yield data/output from a 'copy multiline text' operation which produces a particularly nice outcome when pasted into a multiline field in a form?

@cfr, Can you point in the best direction for .tex to .html resources?

I'm really not the best person to ask. Search this site for TeX4ht or look it up with texdoc maybe? Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136138/tex4ht-prevent-line-breaking-in-html?rq=1 help? Apparently, you'll still get line breaks, but you can limit them before producing the HTML.

Is this something you need to do often? What is the use case exactly? Maybe there are alternative solutions, for example keeping the input as unformatted text (in plain text files, or in a database of some sort), then you can use this unformatted text directly to copy into the web form and you can import it in the LaTeX code when needed via \input{}, or via the csvsimple or datatool packages, or using Python or whichever other solution would fit your needs.
