# Is it ImageMagick's fault or pdflatex's that some JPEGs aren't working?

Tags: graphics, xetex, pdftex, luatex, jpeg

`pdflatex` (as well as `lualatex` and `xelatex`) cannot process (some) JPEG images which were created by my ImageMagick.

I'm on OSX Mavericks, using **ImageMagick `v6.9.0-0 Q16 x86_64`** provided via MacPorts.

My **LaTeX version** installed is this:

```
$ latex --version
 pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/MacPorts 2014_8)
 kpathsea version 6.2.0
 [....]
 Compiled with libpng 1.6.17; using libpng 1.6.17
 Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
 Compiled with poppler version 0.32.0
```

I've tried to construct a minimal working example so everybody can reproduce the problem. If you can't, please tell which exact version of IM and  LaTeX you run.

### Preparation

Here are two JPEGs, both created by ImageMagick.

<strike>The left one isn't working, the right one is:</strike> (see update below the images!)

[image] [image]

> **Update:** Imgur hosting seems to strip some metadata, so the files aren't any longer in their original state. Please use this  **[link on GoogleDrive to a mini-tarball](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-hdTUPc8Sj1YzRwSFdMQ1lybzQ/view?usp=sharing)**. It contains the original JPEGs.

I used these commands to create them:

```
$ convert wizard:              wiz-standard.jpg   # (left image) 
$ convert wizard: -density 300 wiz-300densi.jpg   # (right image)
```

### Data points about the two JPEGs

Here are a few data points about their differences.

#### File sizes

```
$ ls -l wiz-300densi.jpg wiz-standard.jpg 
 -rw-r--r--  1 kp  staff  62177  7 Mai 12:09 wiz-300densi.jpg
 -rw-r--r--  1 kp  staff  62177  7 Mai 12:09 wiz-standard.jpg
```

As you can see, exactly same file sizes.

#### Pixel dimensions

```
$ identify wiz-300densi.jpg wiz-standard.jpg
  wiz-300densi.jpg    JPEG 480x640 480x640+0+0 8-bit sRGB 62.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
  wiz-standard.jpg[1] JPEG 480x640 480x640+0+0 8-bit sRGB 62.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

As you can see, exactly identical image dimensions.

#### Pixel/Color differences

```
$ for i in $(compare -list metric); do 
>     echo -n " Metric  $i :  "; 
>     compare -metric $i wiz-300densi.jpg wiz-standard.jpg null: ; 
>     echo; 
>  done

 Metric  AE    :  0
 Metric  Fuzz  :  0 (0)
 Metric  MAE   :  0 (0)
 Metric  MEPP  :  0 (0, 0)
 Metric  MSE   :  0 (0)
 Metric  NCC   :  1
 Metric  PAE   :  0 (0)
 Metric  PHASH :  0
 Metric  PSNR  :  inf
 Metric  RMSE  :  0 (0)
```

As you can see, comparing the color values of every single pixel does not yield any differences according to every single available metric.

#### Image metadata

```
$ identify -verbose wiz-300densi.jpg > wiz-300densi.log
$ identify -verbose wiz-standard.jpg > wiz-standard.log

$ sdiff -sbB wiz-densi300.log wiz-standard.log
  Image: wiz-300densi.jpg                    | Image: wiz-standard.jpg
    Resolution: 300x300                      <
    Print size: 1.6x2.13333                  <
      date:create: 2015-05-07T12:09:45+02:00 |     date:create: 2015-05-07T12:09:20+02:00
      date:modify: 2015-05-07T12:09:45+02:00 |     date:modify: 2015-05-07T12:09:20+02:00
      filename: wiz-300densi.jpg             |     filename: wiz-standard.jpg
```

Here is the first difference: the "not-working" JPEG does no contain any hint in its metadata about the prefered resolution it wants to be be rendered on an output device.

```
$ exiftool wiz-standard.jpg | grep Resolution
    Resolution Unit                 : inches
    X Resolution                    : 1
    Y Resolution                    : 1

$ exiftool wiz-300densi.jpg | grep Resolution
    Resolution Unit                 : inches
    X Resolution                    : 300
    Y Resolution                    : 300
```

Exiftool also reports a difference: However, it reports not an empty value (like `identify -verbose` did for the "not-working" JPEG), but a value of `1`. I don't know if this is really in the file's data, or if `exiftool` just *assumes* and reports this value in leu of a missing metadata entry.

### LaTeX code (MWE)

Here is my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{./wiz-standard.jpg}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### `pdflatex` run + output

Running `pdflatex` on it yields these messages:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/MacPorts 2014_8) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mini.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 50 languages loaded.
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(./mini.aux) (/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: arithmetic: number too big

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: arithmetic: number too big
<./wiz-standard.jpg, id=1, --32768.0pt x 0.0pt> <use ./wiz-standard.jpg>
[1{/opt/local/var/db/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./wiz-standard.
jpg>] (./mini.aux) )</opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on mini.pdf (1 page, 70603 bytes).
Transcript written on mini.log.
```

So from the MWE-LaTeX above, `pdflatex` at least did generate an output PDF of 70 KiBytes, while giving some warnings, but...

### Empty (white) page

...but the PDF only shows an "empty", white page. (I'll not show a screenshot of it, though  :)

`pdfimages` reports an embedded image in this PDF:

```
$ pdfimages -list mini.pdf
 page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1     0 image     480   640  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no         1  0     2     2 60.7K 6.7%
```

It can even extract the JPEG again from the PDF, and it is in its original shape:

```
$  pdfimages -j  mini.pdf mini---

$ ls -ltar mini----000.jpg wiz-standard.jpg 
 -rw-r--r--  1 kp  staff  62177  7 Mai 12:09 wiz-standard.jpg
 -rw-r--r--  1 kp  staff  62177  8 Mai 02:09 mini----000.jpg
```

Note, that in other cases, with a non-minimal TeX file I also experience a different `pdflatex` message, and the run doesn't complete and no PDF is created at all (not even an empty page):

### `pdflatex` with errors (not just warnings) on non-MWE LaTeX

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: arithmetic: number too big

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: arithmetic: number too big
<./wiz-standard.jpg, id=4, --32768.0pt x 0.0pt>

! Package graphics Error: Division by 0.
See the graphics package documentation for explanation.

Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
l.63 \includegraphics{./wiz-standard.jpg}
?
```

Note the `Division by 0.`-message...

### `lualatex` not completing run with the MWE from above

I also tried `lualatex`. This reports a slightly different message:

```
LuaTeX warning: arithmetic: number too big

LuaTeX warning: arithmetic: number too big
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \dimen@ 

l.8 \includegraphics{./wiz-standard.jpg}

?
```

No PDF is created by `lualatex`, not even an empty page.

### `xelatex` not completing run with the MWE from above

These are `xelatex`'s messages on the MWE:

```
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   b
l.8 \includegraphics{./wiz-standard.jpg}

?
```

No PDF is created by `xelatex`, not even an empty page.

### Questions

Be aware, that the alternative JPEG, which contains the resolution hints, is successfully embedded and a PDF is created by either of the `{pdf,lua,xe}latex` commands.

My questions are:

1. Can you reproduce this problem with your versions of LaTeX and of ImageMagick?
2. Why are `{pdf,lua,xe}latex` relying on some metadata inside a JPEG so much, that it even kills itself when this metadata is wrong (or missing) instead of simply just using the real raster pixel data which is there?
3. Isn't that a bug in the respective components (even if we accept that the JPEG itself may be "buggy") ?!?

---

### Update 1:

(In response to comment by Mike Renfro...)

My non-MWE LaTeX code contains this snippet:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Redefine \includegraphics so that, unless explicit options are
% given, the image width will not exceed the width of the page.
% Images get their normal width if they fit onto the page, but
% are scaled down if they would overflow the margins.
\makeatletter
\def\ScaleIfNeeded{%
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
{%
 \catcode`\@=11\relax%
 \gdef\includegraphics{\@ifnextchar[{\Oldincludegraphics}{\Oldincludegraphics[width=\ScaleIfNeeded]}}%
}%
```

So this should take care of the scaling, no?

---

### Update 2:

The images I linked to originally have been stripped of metadata and are no longer in their original shape.

Here is a **[link on GoogleDrive to a mini-tarball](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-hdTUPc8Sj1YzRwSFdMQ1lybzQ/view?usp=sharing)** containing the original JPEGs.

---

## Update 3

I forgot to mention: I had also tested with

```
$ convert wizard: -density 1 wiz-001densi.jpg
```

So the resulting file does include the respective metadata, and

- `exiftool` reports `{X,Y} Resolution    : 1`, and
- `identify -verbose` reports `Resolution: 1x1`.

(This is already mentioned in my previous postings to the [ImageMagick forums](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27589#p121957) as well as to the [Pandoc forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pandoc-discuss/wvpJlQAaonc/t8U5_cDihf0J).)

So this fact somehow contradicts the some speculations given in some of the answers below...

---

<sup>(In order to resolve the question wether the JPEG itself is buggy, I also reported this issue in the **[appropriate ImageMagick forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27589)**).</sup>

<sup>(**Update:** Just saw a new **[message on the ImageMagick "Bugs" forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27589&start=15#p122059)** by Dirk Lemstra saying: *"I just committed a patch to our SVN repository to make sure that the default density units is set to 0 (unknown) instead of 1 (pixels per inch)."*)</sup>

Comment: I'd guess it's the "1 dpi" resolution, given that you end up with a 3000+ inch image error. I've never included a raster graphic without a `[width=]` parameter. `[width=0.5\textwidth]` or similar is most common. Occasionally `[scale=]`, but not nearly as often.

Comment: @MikeRenfro: I've been asked to provide an MWE, so here it is. I've also updated my posting with he snippet from my non-MWE-TeX code, where this problem occurred the first time. And there the scaling is taken care of... Unless you can point me to the flaw in it (I'm a LaTeX Greenhorn, really.)

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem yet. I downloaded the left image and got a 480x640 pixel image, and OS X Preview reports it at 72 dpi. Not sure if imgur did something to the image along the way. But with no scaling, MacTeX ends up at roughly 480x640 points, or one point per pixel. Your additional `\ScaleIfNeeded` code works fine for me, too.

Comment: @MikeRenfro: Oh, and about the *'3000+ inch image'*. No, that cannot be the problem. Because PDF supports media sizes of up to ~280 kilometers. It is rather that LaTeX sees (or assumes) a `0.0pt` dimension in the Y-direction, and therefor runs into a `divide by 0` error when it tries to scale.

Comment: Yep. I can reproduce the problem. Don't have a solution yet, though. As a workaround, I'd consider fixing the images either using the convert command you're already using, or an Automator workflow.

Comment: @MikeRenfro: I'll delete those of my comments which will not add anything new to the story (now that the OP is updated accordingly...)

Comment: MacTeX 2014, no imagemagick. But your second image works fine for me, as it did for you.

Comment: PDF may support media up to 280km but TeX does not. There is a divide by zero error but there is also a dimension too large error right before that, which I'm assuming is due to the enormous width. @MikeRenfro It is generally possible to include raster images without `width` or anything - just at natural size. It just rarely works out very well unless you've designed the images specifically to fit ;).

Comment: There is a slightly newer version of ImageMagick available, but I have no reason to think it would help in any way.

Comment: @cfr: The "divide by 0" and the "dimensions too large" (*and did you notice the negative sign there!?*) errors might be two sides of the same coin. ImageMagick certainly didn't insert a 0 PPI setting into the file. It was either 1 PPI or no setting at all. In any case this would be a LaTeX bug: with 1 PPI it should calculate with that value, if empty it shouldn't assume "0 PPI".

Comment: @cfr: Do you, by any chance, know what the maximum media dimensions supported by TeX are? And what the maximum image dimensions that can be handled? Where in the TeX world would this be officially documented?

Comment: It is probably in the TeX Book. But you can also probably find it if you search the site with just the right terms... ;).

Comment: @cfr: I was asking for "just the right terms"  :-)

Comment: BTW: `2^15 == 32768`... and pdflatex's error message was: *"number too big <./wiz-standard.jpg, id=4, --32768.0pt x 0.0pt"*.

Comment: See also [Anybody ever encountered "arithmetic: number too big" when importing an image?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207348)

Comment: Hence, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420/whats-the-absolute-largest-paper-size-permissible-with-pdflatex/430#430 gives `16383.99999pt` as the largest dimension TeX can handle.

Comment: In the JFIF header, both a resolution in DPI, commonly `(72, 72)` (with `inches`/`1`), or a pixel ratio, commonly `(1, 1)` (with `None`/`0`), is fine. With ExifTool, you can restore that information, or *keep* it in the first place. To create the former, use `exiftool -jfif:ResolutionUnit=inches -jfif:XResolution=72 -jfif:YResolution=72 <FILES>`. To create the latter, use `exiftool -jfif:ResolutionUnit=None -jfif:XResolution=1 -jfif:YResolution=1 <FILES>`. To strip EXIF (etc.) but keep resolution: `exiftool -all= -TagsFromFile @ -jfif:ResolutionUnit -jfif:XResolution -jfif:YResolution <FILES>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My own conclusion, after running a series of more tests, and after studying a bit more the official [spec for JFIF *(JPEG File Interchange Format)* file format](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf) (PDF) is this:

> 1. ImageMagick is not at fault.
> 2. All of `pdflatex`, `lualatex` and `xelatex` are wrong and exhibit a bug when they do not properly embed the JPEG into the PDF page.

## JFIF spec

The JFIF spec describes 3 fields in the JPEG header:

1. At byte offset `0x0d` the "Units" field.
   This field has a 1 byte length.
   It can hold 3 values.
   The values describe *"Units of the X and Y densities"*.

   - `0`, means: *"no units, X and Y describe the pixel aspect ratios"*.
   - `1`, means: *"X and Y are dots per inch"*;
   - `2`, means: *"X and Y are dots per cm"*.
2. At byte offset `0x0e` the "XDensity" field.
   This field has 2 bytes length.
   It describes the *"Horizontal pixel density"*.
3. At byte offset `0x10` the "YDensity" field.
   Its length is 2 bytes.
   It describes the *"Vertical pixel density"*.

   ```
   +---------------+---------+-----------------+---------------------+
   |   Byte-Offset |   0x0d  |        0x0e     |        0x10         |
   +---------------+---------+-----------------+---------------------+
   |    Field-Name | "Units" |   "XDensity"    |   "YDensity"        |
   +---------------+---------+-----------------+---------------------+
   | Value/Meaning |      0  | "X and Y describe pixel aspect ratio" |
   +---------------+---------+-----------------+---------------------+
   | Value/Meaning |      1  |     "X and Y are dots per inch"       |
   +---------------+---------+-----------------+---------------------+
   | Value/Meaning |      1  |      "X and Y are dots per cm"        |
   +---------------+---------+-----------------+---------------------+
   ```

### Test script

I created a test script (Bash) which does the following:

1. Create JPEG files from the same source passing different `-density` parameters to `convert`.
2. Log different properties of the JPEG files in text files.
3. Use the respective JPEG file in a LaTeX document (MWE) which was created by the same script.
4. Run each of `{pdf,xe,lua}latex` to create a PDF.
5. Log some properties of the PDF files in text files.
6. Uncompress the PDFs' `/Content` streams for manual inspection.

The script code is here:

```
#!/bin/bash
#   Script written by  <kurt AT pfeifle DOT mykolab AT com>
#   No warranty -- 
#     -- feel free to use/modify for whatever purpose -- 
#     -- use at your own risk.

mkdir jpeg-imagemagick-latex-pdflatex-lualatex-xelatex-testing
cd jpeg-imagemagick-latex-pdflatex-lualatex-xelatex-testing
rm -rf testwiz.jpg wiz-*

cat << _EOFHERE_ > mini.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{./testwiz.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
_EOFHERE_

for density in 000 0.2 0.5 0.8 001 1.2 1.5 1.8 002 2.2 2.5 2.6 010 100 ; do

    convert wizard: -density ${density}  wiz-${density}densi.jpg

    md5sum wiz-${density}densi.jpg                    >> wiz-md5sums.txt

    ls -l wiz-${density}densi.jpg                     >> wiz-filesizes.txt

    mkdir pdfoutdir-${density}densi

    ln -fs wiz-${density}densi.jpg testwiz.jpg

    file wiz-${density}densi.jpg                      >> wiz-filemagic.txt

    echo "wiz-${density}densi.jpg :"                  >> wiz-identify-verbose-densi.txt
    identify -verbose wiz-${density}densi.jpg                        \
        | grep -E '(Resolution:|Print size:|filename:)'              \
        | gsed 's#^#   #'                             >> wiz-identify-verbose-densi.txt
    echo "" >> wiz-identify-verbose-densi.txt

    for latexengine in pdflatex lualatex xelatex; do

        echo
        echo mkdir pdfoutdir-${density}densi/${latexengine}
        echo "================================================="
        echo

        mkdir pdfoutdir-${density}densi/${latexengine}

        ${latexengine} -interaction=nonstopmode                       \
            -output-directory=pdfoutdir-${density}densi/${latexengine} mini.tex

        ls -l pdfoutdir-${density}densi/${latexengine}/mini.pdf >> wiz-pdfsizes.txt

        qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable                           \
            pdfoutdir-${density}densi/${latexengine}/mini.pdf         \
            pdfoutdir-${density}densi/${latexengine}/qdf---mini.pdf

        ls -l pdfoutdir-${density}densi/${latexengine}/qdf---mini.pdf \
                                                                >> wiz-qdfsizes.txt
    done
done

for density in std ; do

    convert wizard:              wiz-${density}densi.jpg

    md5sum wiz-${density}densi.jpg                    >> wiz-md5sums.txt

    ls -l wiz-${density}densi.jpg                     >> wiz-filesizes.txt

    mkdir pdfoutdir-${density}densi

    ln -fs wiz-${density}densi.jpg testwiz.jpg

    file wiz-${density}densi.jpg                      >> wiz-filemagic.txt

    echo "wiz-${density}densi.jpg :"                  >> wiz-identify-verbose-densi.txt
    identify -verbose wiz-${density}densi.jpg \
        | grep -E '(Resolution:|Print size:|filename:)' \
        | gsed 's#^#   #'                             >> wiz-identify-verbose-densi.txt
    echo ""                                           >> wiz-identify-verbose-densi.txt

    for latexengine in pdflatex lualatex xelatex; do

        echo
        echo mkdir pdfoutdir-${density}densi/${latexengine}
        echo "================================================="
        echo

        mkdir pdfoutdir-${density}densi/${latexengine}

        ${latexengine} -interaction=nonstopmode                       \
            -output-directory=pdfoutdir-${density}densi/${latexengine} mini.tex

        ls -l pdfoutdir-${density}densi/${latexengine}/mini.pdf >> wiz-pdfsizes.txt

        qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable                           \
            pdfoutdir-${density}densi/${latexengine}/mini.pdf         \
            pdfoutdir-${density}densi/${latexengine}/qdf---mini.pdf

        ls -l pdfoutdir-${density}densi/${latexengine}/qdf---mini.pdf \
                                                                >> wiz-qdfsizes.txt
    done
done

echo
echo wiz-pdfsizes.txt
echo ================
cat  wiz-pdfsizes.txt
echo

echo wiz-qdfsizes.txt
echo ================
cat  wiz-qdfsizes.txt
echo

echo wiz-filesizes.txt
echo =================
cat  wiz-filesizes.txt
echo

echo wiz-filemagic.txt
echo =================
cat  wiz-filemagic.txt
echo

echo wiz-identify-verbose-densi.txt
echo ==============================
cat  wiz-identify-verbose-densi.txt
echo

echo wiz-md5sums.txt
echo ===============
cat  wiz-md5sums.txt | sort

cd -
```

### ImageMagick's different output

My test script for generating JPEGs based on ImageMagick's builtin demo `wizard:` image yielded 3 different results:

1. JFIF headers with "Units" field set to `0` ("pixel aspect ratio") and "X/Y Densities to `0` each.
2. JFIF headers with "Units" field set to `0` ("pixel aspect ratio") and "X/Y Densities to `1` or bigger each.
3. JFIF headers with "Units" field set to `1` ("dots per inch") and "X/Y Densities to `1` each. (I could not successfully set higher values to these fields while the "Units" was set to the default `PixelsPerInch` being equivalent to `1` in the JFIF header).

## `{pdf,xe,lua}latex` behavior

Each of the above three combinations of content in the JFIF header fields led to different results when inserting the respective JPEG into LaTeX-PDFs.
(I didn't test the *"X and Y are dots per **cm**"* variation, which could be generated by additionally passing `-units PixelsPerCentimeter` on the command line. 
By default ImageMagick silently uses `-units PixelsPerInch`.)

Here are the details:

1. **`Units == 0`** ("X and Y describe pixel aspect ratios") with **`XxY == 0x0`** (XDensity x YDensity):

   - This causes `xelatex` to mis-place and mis-scale the image on the page.
     It is then only partially visible.
   - `pdflatex` has no problem here and creates a correct PDF page.
   - `lualatex` has no problem here and creates a correct PDF page.
   - The condition in the JPEG was created with this command:
     `convert wizard: -density 0.2 wiz-0.2densi.jpg`
     (Note that I "abused" the parameter by passing `-density 0.2` -- pixels normally don't come in fracions... :)
2. **`Units == 0`** ("X and Y describe pixel aspect ratios") with **`XxY == 1x1`** or **`XxY == 2x2`** or **`XxY == 3x3`** or ...  (XDensity x YDensity):

   - This causes no problem, for neither of `{pdf,xe,lua}latex`.
   - All PDF pages look correctly here.
     They are also identical to each other.
   - So the actual value of these two fields didn't matter, as long as it wasn't `0 / 0`.
     (I didn't test with `0 / 1` or `1 / 0` or `0 / 2` or `2 / 0` or any similar combination, though.)
   - This condition in the JPEG was created with the command:
     `convert wizard: -density 001 wiz-001densi.jpg`
     (Note that passing `-density 0.5` -- or `0.8` or `1` or `1.2` -- all inserted also `1/1` into the "X/YDensity" fields, despite of using "fractions" for the pixel settings...)
3. **`Units == 1`** ("X and Y are dots per inch") with **`XxY == 1x1`** (XDensity x YDensity):

   - This causes each of `{pdf,xe,lua}latex` to create a PDF with an empty, white page.
   - Each of these PDF producers emits different warnings or error messages during its run.
   - This condition in the JPEG I could create with two different commands:
     `convert wizard:             wiz-001densi.jpg` or
     `convert wizard: -density 0  wiz-001densi.jpg`

In all cases where the resulting PDF had a white page only or where the image was only partially visible the JPEG image data was completely embedded and...

1. ...I could again extract a valid and unbroken JPEG image with the help of the `pdfimages` command line tool;
2. ...I could uncompress the `/Contents` stream in the respective PDF, change a few parameters for the `cm` operator and make the image to become visible.

Here is what had to be changed in the `/Contents` streams:

### 1. PPDF files created by **`pdflatex`**

- created from **`wiz-stddensi.jpg`** or from **`wiz-000densi.jpg`**:

  ```
  +--------------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
  |              |           PDF source code line                 | Image on PDF page   |
  +--------------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
  | In PDF obj 5 | -32645.5791 0 0 -32645.5791 357.908 706.129 cm | invisible (outside) |
  |    Change to |  480        0 0    640      124.802  76.093 cm | Image now visible   |
  +--------------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
  ```
- created from all other JPEGs: PDFs were OK.

### 2. PDF files created by **`xelatex`**

- created from **`wiz-stddensi.jpg`** or from **`wiz-000densi.jpg`**:

  ```
  +--------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+
  |              |           PDF source code line          | Image on PDF page   |
  +--------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+
  | In PDF obj 5 | 34560 0 0 46080 52.8  -63.76 cm /Im0 Do | invisible (outside) |
  |    Change to |   480 0 0   640 52.8 -693.8  cm /Im0 Do | Image now visible   |
  +--------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+
  ```
- created from **`wiz-0.2densi.jpg`**:*

  ```
  +--------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+
  |              |           PDF source code line          | Image on PDF page   |
  +--------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+
  | In PDF obj 5 |   480 0 0   640 52.8  -63.76 cm /Im0 Do | partially outside   |
  |    Change to |   480 0 0   640 52.8 -693.8  cm /Im0 Do | Image now visible   |
  +--------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+
  ```
- created from all other JPEGs: PDFs were OK.

### 3. PDF files created by **`lualatex`**

- created from **`wiz-stddensi.jpg`** or from **`wiz-000densi.jpg`**:

  ```
  +--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
  |              |           PDF source code line                         | Image on PDF page   |
  +--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
  | In PDF obj 5 | -32645.5776 0 0 -32645.5776 124.802 706.129 cm /Im1 Do | invisible (outside) |
  |    Change to |     481     0 0    640      124.802  76.093 cm /Im1 Do | Image now visible   |
  +--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
  ```
- created from all other JPEGs: PDFs were OK.

## Inserting other JFIF header values with exiftool

After I inserted various other values of JFIF headers into the JPEG file (with the help of `exiftool`), it turned out that each `*latex` PDF generator:

1. ...successfully created a valid PDF when embedding the JPEG into its pages, but
2. ...didn't actually seem to care about scaling, resolution and aspect ratios requested by the header.

All generators only seem to trip over the JFIF header when the following condition applied:

```
+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+
| Byte-Offset |                   0x0d  |      0x0e  |      0x10  |
+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+
|  Field-Name |                 "Units" | "XDensity" | "YDensity" |
+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                      1  |      1     |    1       |
+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+
|     Meaning | "X/YDensities are DPI"  |      1 dpi |    1 dpi   |
+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+
```

Funnily the following condition  lets none of the PDF generators trip.
This is despite the "more extreme" setting for "X/YDensity" to **`0`**.
`pdflatex` and `lualatex` generate a valid PDF looking as it ought to look.
`xelatex` however places most part of the image outside of the pages `/MediaBox`:

```
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
| Byte-Offset |                       0x0d  |      0x0e  |      0x10  |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|  Field-Name |                     "Units" | "XDensity" | "YDensity" |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                          0  |      0     |    0       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|     Meaning | "X/YDensities pixel ratios" |      0 px  |    0 px    |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
```

### "X/YDensities pixel ratios"

All of the *following* conditions let `pdflatex` and `lualatex` work produce valid PDFs.
Each one looking identical, regardless the actual X/YDensity values.
None is scaled, buckled or stretched in any way.
Each JPEG is displayed on the PDF page with a resolution of 72 PPI.

```
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
| Byte-Offset |                       0x0d  |      0x0e  |      0x10  |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|  Field-Name |                     "Units" | "XDensity" | "YDensity" |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                          0  |      7     |    7       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                          0  |    100     |  100       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                          0  |    200     |  200       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                          0  |    300     |  300       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                          0  |    100     |  300       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                          0  |    300     |  100       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                          0  |    300     |    1       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|     Meaning | "X/YDensities pixel ratios" | <above> px | <above> px |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
```

Most of the time `xelatex` also produced identical output. In the last, extreme case where XDensity was set to 300 and YDensity to 1, `xelatex` moved the biggest part of the image to outside of the `/MediaBox`.

### "X/YDensities are DPI"

All of the *following* conditions lets all three, `xelatex`, `pdflatex` and `lualatex` work produce valid PDFs.
The results for the three tools are slighly different, but seem to actually follow the given X/YDensity values.
If the value of "XDensity" is different from the value for "YDensity" the image is scaled or buckled.
For identical values between the two fields the image is scaled accordingly keeping the aspect ratio: 
small values enlarge the image, large values scale it down.

```
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
| Byte-Offset |                       0x0d  |      0x0e  |      0x10  |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|  Field-Name |                     "Units" | "XDensity" | "YDensity" |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                          1  |      7     |    7       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                          1  |    100     |  100       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                          1  |    200     |  200       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                          1  |    300     |  300       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                          1  |    100     |  300       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                          1  |    300     |  100       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|       Value |                          1  |    300     |    1       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|     Meaning |      "X/YDensities are DPI" | <above> px | <above> px |
+-------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
```

## Scope of this bug

ImageMagick does not change the JFIF headers of JPEGs it processes, unless told so on the command line.

So there is probably no danger for lots of people running into this bug when they create PDFs through LaTeX which include their precious digital photos.

This bug initially showed up because I used the builtin IM special file named `wizard:` as a source to create a JPEG.
This triggered the extreme case of this bug, because unfortunately ImageMagick used a default DPI value of "1" for its output file (which in itself is probably a bug in ImageMagick).

This case can be worked around in ImageMagick by adding f.e. `-density 72` to the command line.

However, it is still very questionable for the `*latex` PDF producing utilities to use the JFIF header metadata ***AT ALL*** for embedding JPEG images into pages. 
Because:

- most users are unaware of these JFIF headers
- most users don't know how to change these headers
- these headers control the scaling of JPEGs on PDF pages only *indirectly*
- most users expect to control the scaling of images in PDF output by different (LaTeX-provided) means *directly*
- the treatment of the various JFIF headers is inconsistent:

  - if set as "X/Densities are DPI" they are ***NOT*** respected.
  - if set as "X/YDensities are pixel ratios" they are (somehow) respected.

### Executive Summary

> - The LaTeX-family PDF generators behave totally unreasonable here. 
>     On the one hand, whatever value "XDensity" and "YDensity" field hold if they are given as "DPI", they are ***NOT*** respected.
>     On the other hand, if the "XDensity" and "YDensity" fields hold values meant to be "pixel aspect ratios", they ***ARE*** influencing the scaling of images on a page, but in very un-expected ways.
> - The LaTeX PDF-generators should ignore the JFIF fields completely and only obey the statements given by the documents LaTeX code.
>     In the absence of such code, the PDF generators should assume 72 DPI.

Comment: It is one thing if a user specifies absolute dimensions for scaling, but if they say e.g. `scale=.5` that doesn't help. And to always ignore a specified DPI and impose a value seems potentially problematic. But I agree that they should treat the data *consistently*.

Comment: there isn't really a "latex family" involved here, firstly latex isn't involved, latex just relies on the underlying tex engine to report the image size, so if there is a bug it is a bug (separately) in pdftex, luatex and xdvipdfmx (the dvi driver used by xetex)

Comment: Can you please open a bug with LuaTeX so we can track it there (a plain TeX test file would be much preferred)? I still believe we do it right, though...

Comment: @MartinSchröder: ***[Done!](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=937)*** *(But I must say, this bug tracking software's editor is, from a user's point of view one of the most crappy interfaces to handle. Can't you at least set it up with a mono-spaced font?!)*

Comment: the test script creates the mini.tex file in the wrong directory; move that statement to just before the first `for` statement.

Comment: @WyboDekker: Thanks for noticing. Copy'n'paste error -- my real script is longer and does more things, so I copied only a few sections.

Answer (score 19):

As it happens I stumbled upon the same problem last week and the next version of LuaTeX will detect these images and issue a warning:

```
LuaTeX warning (file wiz-standard.jpg): The image specifies an unusual resolution of 1dpi by 1dpi.
```

pdfTeX/luaTeX read jpegs bytewise (no exif involved) and images of these kind *really* specify a resolution of 1dpi by 1dpi (see [the JFIF spec](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf), page 5). This typically gives images that are too large for TeX to handle (see `\maxdimen`; the limit would be around 200 x 200 pixels). wiz-standard.jpg has 480x640 pixels, so TeX thinks you want to include an image that's 480inx640in - that's way too large.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback as well as the LuaTeX fix (whoever is responsible for it -- you?).

Comment: @KurtPfeifle: Me. I was at a TeX conference ([BachoTeX](http://www.gust.org.pl/bachotex/2015-en)) with the LuaTeX developers in the same room and a friend had the exact same problem: Some of his hundreds of images would show this problem.

Answer (score 13):

The image `wiz-standard.jpg` does not have any resolution DPI settings set (the other image is set to 300 and 300).

Several image software packages do not set this properly as it is rarely used (including by TeX as far as I know), but for some odd reason TeX requires it to be set (to anything you like - because it is not used - whether you choose 100x100 or 400x400 you will get the same LaTeX output).

It is called the JFIF header which actually doesn't need to exist in JPEG anyway - so it's a bug in LaTeX as far as I am concerned.

You can correct it (in a lossy way) by re-saving the file; but you can also do it losslessly by simply adding the DPI values to the header.

This works in Windows, but may work on other platforms:

- Use `exiftool` as a command line tool (you can do this in the `exiftoolgui` via `exiftooldirect` button) to add in a special header.

  These are the command line arguments to `exiftool`:

  ```
  -jfif:Xresolution=300  -jfif:Yresolution=300  -jfif:ResolutionUnit=inches
  ```

  The `inches` may be replaced by `cm` or `None` to insert the other two valid values for the respective field.

**Added information:** Clearly DPI information is used by \includegraphics if no size is specified - I tried a few experiments, and if there is a JFIF header, and if the image is set at its "natural" resolution with

```
\includegraphics{xxxx.jpg}
```

then the image size in the compiled PDF does depend on the DPI. However if any option is set to constrain the height or width the DPI setting is ignored. It seems reasonable to me that compilation should not fail if the DPI is missing but is not used because it is irrelevant. Interestingly the option `[resolution=300,width=0.3\textwidth]` does not correct the error as (I think) the resolution option to `\includegraphics` only works if the JFIF is absent (rather than present with no DPI setting)

Comment: I appreciate our feedback. *"TEX requires it to be set (to anything ...)"*. I can confirm that: it works even when set to `1x1`. I had forgotten to mention this in my original posting. Yes, it is a stupid bug in TeX/LaTeX/pdflatex -- I came to that conclusion meanwhile. It is a pain in the ass to try and "fix" all those conforming JPEGs after they killed a `pdflatex` run...

Comment: The image in question _explicitely_ declares itself has a JFIF image having "X and Y are dots per inch" and then 1 horizontal pixel density and 1 vertical pixel density. See the [JFIF spec, page 5](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf).

Comment: I think we can word the bug in a different way: DPI data may or may not exist in jpg images. Some image software is DPI aware and uses the DPI. LaTex is DPI aware and requires the DPI, but does not actually use the DPI.

Comment: An earlier comment of mine reads: *"I appreciate our feedback."* Of course it should be *your* feedback which I appreciate. My keyboard is bouncing and blocking for individual keystrokes, and I do not always notice it immediately...

Comment: Clearly part of my answer is incorrect - I have corrected

Comment: I somehow wound up with a JPG file with invalid EXIF metadata about height and width. I stripped the EXIF data as detailed here and it worked: https://linuxnightly.com/how-to-remove-exif-data-via-linux-command-line/