# Dimension too large in \includegraphics

Tags: scaling, includegraphics, jpeg

I want to include this image (shown below) at the right side of my page, surrounded by text. But I got the following error

```
! Dimension too large.<argument> \wd \@tempboxa l.291 ...phics[width=3cm, height=5cm]{vinyeta.jpg}
! Dimension too large.<argument> \ht \@tempboxa l.291 ...phics[width=3cm, height=5cm]{vinyeta.jpg}
```

I am using this code

```
\documentclass[12,twoside]{mammeTFM}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} } %Images' path, for efficiency.
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{5cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=5cm]{vinyeta.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With [width=\textwidth] there is no space left for text.  Not to mention the \columnsep gap.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I changed the code, so its more realisitc. I tried to insert a \rule{3cm}{7cm} and worked perfectly, but with the images is not working.

Comment: Your example does not match your error messages. Your error comes from an \includegraphics command with "keepaspectratio" in its options. Show *that* command.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau I corrected the error, I edites my wrapfigure environment multiple times, that's why the error was not matching the example.

Comment: Those errors don't come from wrapfigure though, they come from \includegraphics with something wrong in the arguments.

Comment: I think that the issue is due to the particular JPG file.

Comment: @egreg That made the trick. I changed the format from JPG to PNG and now it is working perfectly.

Comment: @BeanGuy Conversion from JPG to PNG is to avoid, in general; you need to fix the JPG instead.

Comment: Did you save your image with ImageMagick? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243791/5763

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some cameras will add metadata to the image that provokes this error message.  The most expedient way to fix this is to remove the nonessential metadata.

If you have the `exiftool` package installed, this is easy:

```
exiftool -all=  -overwrite_original myimage.jpg
```

Comment: Right. An alternative may be to save it as .png or .bmp .

Comment: I tried that, with ImageMagick's convert and with Gimp.  In both cases the error remained.