# Dimension too large for one image

Tags: graphics

I want to include one image ([G0004.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5M7S.jpg)) and I got the following error:

> ```
> D:\Documents\HEIA\Physique\Analyse_spectrale\temp.tex:16: Dimension too large. [...cs[width=0.95\textwidth]{images/G0004.jpg}]
> D:\Documents\HEIA\Physique\Analyse_spectrale\temp.tex:16: Dimension too large. [...cs[width=0.95\textwidth]{images/G0004.jpg}]
> ```

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{ a4paper, margin=2.5cm }
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[squaren,Gray]{SIunits}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage {array}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{images/G0004.jpg}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: My picture]
Thx for your help

Comment: Your image is probably too large, you should reduce with some external tool. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257153/dimension-too-large-error-from-pdflatex-when-using-includegraphics

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with your uploaded image.

Comment: My image is 700x600 px. I if y try with another one, i dont have the error.

Comment: @Warok This is exactly the one i used(700x600 px see). It works. Try to move the image in the same folder.

Comment: Uploaded images inserted here in the questions are not the originals graphics. You would have to put it to some upload service if someone should inspect it. Perhaps it has some faulty resolution.

Comment: I tried with the image in the same folder, same error. I also tried to remove the aux file : same error...

Comment: and here is the original image 
http://imgur.com/a/z3I81

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with the image from your *original image* link and the example code from your question.

Comment: Don't use imgur to upload the image. imgur changes images. Put it in a zip-file and then use a file service.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{images/G0004.jpg}
```

you should try

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=0.9\textheight, 
                 keepaspectratio]{images/G0004.jpg}
```

Since the `figure` environment contains a caption but (apparently) no legend, it should suffice to set aside about `0.1\textheight` to place the caption material.

Incidentally, since the float is almost certainly going to occupy an entire page, you might as well replace `\begin{figure}[htbp]` with `\begin{figure}[p]`. If nothing else, there'll be less code clutter.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but the example image is in landscape format (W:H = 700:600) and the paper is A4 (portrait) so this should not be the problem here.

Comment: @Schweinebacke - Thanks. Let's see if the OP provides more information about the natural dimensions of the file `G0004.jpg`.

Comment: @Mico  your method will not works for one figure: \includegraphics[width=0.0009\textwidth, height=0.0009\textheight, 
keepaspectratio]{./figure/figure8/ab01}

Comment: @acsdaswe - A message such as "your method will not work" is not all that specific and hence is not actionable. *What exactly* isn't "working"? Is LaTeX throwing an error message? If so, what does the message say? At any rate, I'm afraid I fail to understand your intended use case: What are you trying to achieve by displaying an image whose height and width dimensions are so minuscule as to make the image virtually invisible except under exceptionally high magnification? Please elaborate.